# How do I get the address for an element in a Python array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to get the address of an element at a particular index in a Numpy or regular Python array. I'm following a class on Coursera where the instructor gets the address but I'm confused as to if I can do the same in Python since the class is taught in another language. Here's a mathematical sample of what I'm trying to accomplish with code: http://www.guideforschool.com/625348-memory-address-calculation-in-an-array/

Here's what I'd like to do. Let's say I have the following array with the indices:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I'd like to calculate the address for index 4, so here's the calculation:

```
array_address + elem_size x (index - first_index)
```

I need the first item, the array_address or Base address. I've tried this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ndarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
print(a.__array_interface__['data'])
```

But I keep getting a different value every time I run it and it's not for 1 particular index.

I'm sure I'll never have to do these calculations but I want to understand everything I'm learning in depth. Or will I use it? What are some examples of when I would use this?

Comment: Note that array indices start with 0 in Python.

Comment: Every time you create an object in Python (i.e. `a = ...`) it will potentially (and usually) have a different address in memory. You probably just want to create `a` once and then do the rest of your calculations based on `a`'s unchanging memory address.

Comment: The concept of address is not useful in python like it in c. There are no pointers (outside ctypes or other [ffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)). This is just one of those things that doesn't translate as you make the jump from a low/mid-level language to a high level one. That aside, the elements of a list (cant say for certain wrt numpy) are not contiguous. It's simply an array of references to independently allocated elements, so you cant say that the 4th element is at base_address + 4, it could be anywhere.

Comment: If you wanted to construct an array with elements from 1 to 7, `a = np.ndarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` is not how you do it. You want `np.array`. If you want an array indexed by integers from 1 to 7, NumPy doesn't work like that. All NumPy arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks for the clarification. The class I'm taking is mainly taught in C, so I may just bypass this exercise but wanted to understand in depth. Also, when is the memory address important in real world applications?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, I see. Numpy is only zero-based. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: From my point of view (embedded systems developers would add more things). It's just important to understand what pointers are and how you can safely manipulate them. You use pointers a lot in c but in python, you are free from those low level, easy to misuse mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array and its attributes:

```
In [28]: arr = np.arange(1,8)
In [29]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[29]: 
{'data': (41034176, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (7,),
 'version': 3}
```

The data buffer location for a slice:

```
In [30]: arr[4:].__array_interface__['data'][0]
Out[30]: 41034208
In [31]: arr[4:].__array_interface__['data'][0]-arr.__array_interface__['data'][0]
Out[31]: 32
```

The slice shares the data buffer, but with an offset of 4 elements (4*8).

Using this information I can fetch a slice using the `ndarray` constructor (not usually needed):

```
In [35]: np.ndarray((3,), dtype=int, buffer=arr.data, offset=32)
Out[35]: array([5, 6, 7])
In [36]: arr[4:7]
Out[36]: array([5, 6, 7])
```

---

`arr.data` is a `memoryview` object that somehow references the data buffer of this array.  The id/address of `arr.data` is not the same as the data pointer I used above.

```
In [38]: arr.data
Out[38]: <memory at 0x7f996d950e88>
In [39]: type(arr.data)
Out[39]: memoryview
```

---

Note that data location for `arr[4]` is totally different.  It is 'unboxed', not a slice:

```
In [37]: arr[4].__array_interface__
Out[37]: 
{'data': (38269024, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (),
 'version': 3,
 '__ref': array(5)}
```

Comment: Worth noting: this is a simple case, 1-dimensional with strides None. For more complex cases, you also need to take into account the stride length, whether data is row or column major, is it owndata or a view in the first place, etc