# Why does numpy.ndarray's data address change?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6, numpy-ndarray

I recently ran this in a jupyter notebook (cell), because I wanted to verify memory-address behavior of a numpy array when slicing. The slicing is left out, though, to create a minimal failing example.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(10)

x.data.__repr__(), x.data, x.data.__repr__()
```

I was surprised that the last value differs from the first two:

```py
('<memory at 0x7f04073a6ac8>',
  <memory at 0x7f04073a6ac8>,
 '<memory at 0x7f04073a6b88>')
```

I added an extra space to the second tuple-item, to visually align the memory addresses.

What does jupyter do to `x` to change `x.data.__repr__()`, in particular `0x7f04073a6ac8` (`6c8`) into `0x7f04073a6b88` (`b88`)?

## UPDATE, w.r.t jdehesa's comment

This also happens in 'raw' python 3.6, so it's not IPython- or Jupyter-related.

Surprisingly, this only happens when using *one* print-statement for *three* values.

```py
$ cat moving_memory.py 
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(10)

print(x.data.__repr__())
print(x.data)
print(x.data.__repr__())

print(x.data.__repr__(), x.data, x.data.__repr__())

$ python3.6 moving_memory.py 
<memory at 0x7f3f49b02dc8>
<memory at 0x7f3f49b02dc8>
<memory at 0x7f3f49b02dc8>
<memory at 0x7f3f49b02dc8> <memory at 0x7f3f49b02dc8> <memory at 0x7f3f49b02e88>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that is but it does not seem to be related to Jupyter. Running the same in a bare Python interpreter yields a similar result.

Comment: Good point! I am quite clueless where this comes from, and indeed falsely assumed Jupyter, I will update.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: The address printed by repr appears to be the address of the memory object itself, not of the actual memory. Try `m = x.data` `hex(id(m))` and compare to `repr(m)`

Comment: `ndarray.data` is not an instance attribute but a descriptor. You shouln'd expect `x.data` to always return the same object.

Comment: If you want the address of the actual data buffer you can use `x.ctypes.data`

Comment: Use `x.__array_interface__`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51146054/901925

Comment: And [Numpy , Python3.6 - not able to understand why address is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032545/numpy-python3-6-not-able-to-understand-why-address-is-different).  `x.data` is a memoryview object.  Its display name has nothing to do with the location of the array databuffer.